# Getting an input field to recognize it has been populated by clicking on an element and passing that attribute to the filed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have a plugin I am trying to modify. It uses an input field to take an amount, validate the input and show/hide the "Pay Now" button. It was originally coded to handle select options and manual input. That pat looks like this:

```
 if (!gift_this_product.length) {
        $('.gift-cards-list input.ywgc-manual-amount').addClass('ywgc-hidden');
        $('.ywgc-manual-amount-error').remove();

        var amount = 0;

        if ((select_element.length == 0) || ("-1" == select_element.val())) {
            /* the user should enter a manual value as gift card amount */
            var manual_amount_element = $('.gift-cards-list input.ywgc-manual-amount');
            if (manual_amount_element.length) {
                var manual_amount = manual_amount_element.val();
                manual_amount_element.removeClass('ywgc-hidden');

                var test_amount = new RegExp('^[1-9]\\d*(?:' + '\\' + ywgc_data.currency_format_decimal_sep + '\\d{1,2})?$', 'g')

                if (manual_amount.length && !test_amount.test(manual_amount)) {
                    manual_amount_element.after('<div class="ywgc-manual-amount-error">' + ywgc_data.manual_amount_wrong_format + '</div>');
                    show_gift_card_editor(false);
                }
                else {
                    /** If the user entered a valid amount, show "add to cart" button and gift card
                     *  editor.
                     */
                    if (manual_amount) {
                        // manual amount is a valid numeric value
                        show_gift_card_editor(true);

                        amount = accounting.unformat(manual_amount, ywgc_data.mon_decimal_point);
                        console.log(amount);
                        if (amount <= 0) {
                            show_gift_card_editor(false);
                        }
                        else {
                            amount = accounting.formatMoney(amount, {
                                symbol: ywgc_data.currency_format_symbol,
                                decimal: ywgc_data.currency_format_decimal_sep,
                                thousand: ywgc_data.currency_format_thousand_sep,
                                precision: ywgc_data.currency_format_num_decimals,
                                format: ywgc_data.currency_format
                            });
```

When you type into "ywgc-manual-maount" input field, the "Pay Now" button is shown (so long as input is valid). It is triggering this code:

```
 $(document).on('input', '.gift-cards-list input.ywgc-manual-amount', function (e) {
    show_hide_add_to_cart_button();
});
```

The function "show_hide_add_to_cart_button" is the first code block I included.

What I did was to create buttons, and then add a click event that gets the value of the button (as attr), saves it as a variable and then passes it into the "ymgc-manual-amoun" field. It works, but it doesn't update the amount nor reveal the "pay now" button. Here is my function:

```
  var buttonValue = 0;

    $('.amount-button').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
                buttonValue = $(this).attr("value");
                $('.gift-cards-list input.ywgc-manual-amount').focus();
                $('.gift-cards-list input.ywgc-manual-amount').val(buttonValue);   
            });
```

Is this a scope issue, or is it simply to do with the way "val" works when populating the input field?

Comment: what is your original trigger event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying a value with Javascript doesn't trigger events like `change` and `input`. You have to trigger it it explicitly.

```
$('.amount-button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    buttonValue = $(this).attr("value");
    $('.gift-cards-list input.ywgc-manual-amount').focus();
    $('.gift-cards-list input.ywgc-manual-amount').val(buttonValue).trigger("input");   
});
```

Comment: BOOM. That did it. Thanks. Will accept answer as soon as it lets me.